# Is it possible to increment timestamp in str_replace?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, increment, str-replace

I have an xml file that I am rewriting parts of, and I need to increment the timestamp by a millisecond (or second) with each str_replace. I have found tutorials for incrementing, and for adding a second to a timestamp, but not for adding time DURING a loop or with each replace instance.

my replace code looks like this:

```
$data = str_replace("</tag1><tag2>", "</tag1><myDate>".date(DATE_ATOM)."</myDate><tag2>", $data);
```

(to clarify, there are multiple instances of the pattern above in the file)

The replacement as is works, but can't figure out how to add a millisecond or second to the date string at each occurrence, so they are all unique.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks to vascowhite for pointing me in the right direction, I had to combine this with some DOM manipulation, but it works! Here is the solution, for those that wanted to know:

```
$domsrc = file_get_contents("output.xml");
$MYdom = new DomDocument();
$MYdom->loadXML($domsrc);
$date = new DateTime();
$oneSecond = new DateInterval('PT1S');

$descriptions = $MYdom->getElementsByTagName('myDate');
foreach($descriptions as $nodeDesciption)
{
    $nodeDesciption->nodeValue = $date->format(DATE_ATOM);
    $date->add($oneSecond);
}
$MYdom->save("DOMoutput.xml");
```

Comment: I have scoured the web and can't find anywhere that deals with these two things together (str_replace and TIME incrementing). I can find one or the other, but incrementing solutions do not deal with time. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%, but I'll take a shot at answering it.

You first need to get the current time and setup your increment period (1 second) outside your loop:-

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$oneSecond = new \DateInterval('PT1S');
```

Then inside your loop replace your current code with this:-

```
$data = str_replace("</tag1><tag2>", "</tag1><myDate>".$date->format(DATE_ATOM)."</myDate><tag2>", $data);
$date->add($oneSecond);
```

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) for information on the DateTime classes I have used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't seem to make this work. I have an open file where I keep rewriting all the data, then at the end save my file. But how can I make a loop with str_replace stopping at each occurrence to be replaced?

I tried reloading the file using simplexml_load_file and then applying your logic, but it gave me errors...I am going down that road now trying things, I will write back here in a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: OMG combining your suggestion with some other DOM reading, I now have the whole thing working, thanks!